# liquibase maven plugin not working on *unix

Tags: java, macos, maven, liquibase

Everything works great in company on windows7,

When I tried to build the project in home on mac I had several errors,

After some tables created, first error was with first insert script

```
insert into table (ID) values ("1")
```

But this works

```
insert into table (ID) values (1)
```

So I tried to run dropFirst as I usually do, but its wasn't running at all

```
mvn clean install -Dliquibase.dropFirst=true
```

But when I add skipTests params first, it does triggers dropFirst I see in console, but it says object(sequence) already in use, so its not clearing db

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dliquibase.dropFirst=true
```

I updated the maven plugin to 3.2.2 and tested on a ubuntu machine with vagrant where the oracle db current is as well,

Any help will be really appreciate

Comment: It looks like several issues you are seeing. For the insert, you were not seeing it put quotes around the '1' when you were running Liquibase on windows? In the `<insert>` tag are you using valueNumeric="1" or value="1" ?  Can you include the changeLog in the question?

Comment: For the dropAll issue, can you post the actual exception? Do you have a trigger or something referencing the sequence that would keep it from being dropped? (Liquibase does not know how to snapshot triggers and therefore will not drop them)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Liquibase's dropFirst feature is of limited use.  It only drops tables in the schema owned by the username your JDBC connection logs in as.  If you want to drop tables in other schemas, you must do it yourself.